# Replace (NOT restore) directory in within Ubuntu's etc directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-server

I accidentally removed my /etc/samba folder from my installation of Ubuntu Server 12.04. Where can I get a new copy of the folder as it comes with a fresh installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask `dpkg` about all packages that should have a file in this folder by

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/samba
```

then issuing

```
# apt-get install --reinstall package1 package2 ...
```

should reinstall these packages and hence restore the configuration files.

You might also want to have a look at [etckeeper](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/), a tool to keep `/etc` in a git repository (and hence easily recover from mistakes such as the above).

Comment: `dpkg -S /etc/samba` returns samba-common. After apt-get purge samba-common and apt-get install samba-common, I still get "not found" when trying to ls /etc/samba

Comment: Ah, right, yes, sorry. Try the solution in http://serverfault.com/a/363418 , the config file handling is sometimes a little bit…strange :-)